# Remove a specific item from Listbox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm stil new coding and I'm working on a small app for work to smooth some processes.

I'm trying to remove a certain entry from a listbox.

This is an example of what the listbox contains:
54 54 56 56 58 60 60

How can i remove the entries that are not repeated? In this case, the 58 would be removed.

The number of entries in the listbox can vary between 1 and 8.

I have tried multiple things with looping through the listbox but nothing has been close to solve the problem.

```
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step 2
        If ListBox1.Items(i) <> ListBox1.Items(i + 1) Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
 Next
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you remove an item, the indexes of all items below change, so removing in a `For` loop as you're doing won't work. You need to count backwards, so that you remove from the bottom up, because removing an item doesn't affect the indexes of items above.

Comment: Also, don't step by 2. Even if you can't have three items the same in a row, you're still going to skip items that you should be checking.

Comment: You could add you *numbers* to a `List(Of String)` and remove the non-duplicates using LINQ. If you group the item, you can then take only those where the group count is `> 0`. Some thing like `Dim allDupes = numbers.GroupBy(Function(n) n).Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).SelectMany(Function(g) g).ToList()`. You can use the resulting List as the `ListBox.DataSource`.

Comment: Even without the `.RemoveAt` you would have an Index Out of Range error. When your loop reaches the maximum value of '.Count -1` , ListBox1.Items(i + 1) will be out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not too elegant but it should work for any number of list items in any order. You have depended heavily on the order and grouping of the list.

Comments in line.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create a list to hold the indexes to remove
    Dim RemoveIndex As New List(Of Integer)
    'put the items in the list box into an array of Integers
    Dim Numbers = (From n In ListBox1.Items
                   Select CInt(n)).ToArray
    'Loop through the numbers that came from the list box
    For i = 0 To Numbers.Count - 1
        '.LastIndexOf looks in the array (starting at the beginning each time) for Numbers(i)
        Dim LastIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(Numbers, Numbers(i))
        'If it is not the item we are searching for 
        If LastIndex <> i Then
            'Add both to the list
            RemoveIndex.Add(LastIndex)
            RemoveIndex.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
    'Remove duplicates from the list. We can't remove the same item twice
    'Order by the highest index first. That way we won't mess up the lower indexes
    'and we will remove the item/index we expect.
    Dim DistinctList = RemoveIndex.Distinct().OrderByDescending(Function(x) x)
    'Loop through the list (remember the highest index is first)
    For Each index In DistinctList
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very well explained code and tips, it works. I knew i was far from the solution, i tried multiple stuff around the for-loop, but when 1 problem got fixed, new others came up. Jimi solution also worked perfectly. Thanks all

Comment: You are welcome. @Jimi's solution is certainly more elegant.